# need assistance with solving this database error

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to create a user account and i got this error message.

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1048
>
> Column 'group_id' cannot be null

```
INSERT INTO `bitauth_users` (`username`, `password`, `active`, `activation_code`, `group_id`, `password_last_set`) VALUES ('FAAN', '0884e4e5928d672b182a37b885b5e6ec', 1, '7c6ef5bd05fd2d189df64da76e76017ecec7d233', NULL, '2016-06-23 04:07:08')
```

Filename: C:\inetpub\vhosts\vidoplus.com\httpdocs\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Please what do i need to do to fix this. i am new at this. Thanks

Comment: You can't pass a null value to group_id. If group_id is a key in another table, make sure that table is populated first.

Comment: Doesn't the error message tell you the exact issue? `Column 'group_id' cannot be null`. You have column `group_id` and are passing it `NULL`. Update the table scheme.

Answer (score 2):

As `group_id` itself suggest that it's a primary key of some table (I think its will be `groups` table) and treated as a foreign-key in your `bitauth_users` table.

So you can not pass `NULL` to it.

You have to pass some value which is related to the table where it is primary key.

***Note:- please provide some real value (don't provide empty or 0 etc because at the time of fetching record you will face problem)***

Comment: Finally...a non-lazy answer

Answer (score -2):

Form your error message, you need to give value of group_id (not null value). You can try this:

```
INSERT INTO bitauth_users (username, password, active, activation_code, group_id, password_last_set) VALUES ('FAAN', '0884e4e5928d672b182a37b885b5e6ec', 1, '7c6ef5bd05fd2d189df64da76e76017ecec7d233', 1, '2016-06-23 04:07:08');
```

Hope it will help ;)

Comment: pls do i need to set this value using phpmyadmin or do i go to the file directory as specified and look for line 330 to make the changes

Comment: Before do that, can you add to post the php code in your post?

Comment: Assuming group_id is a foreign key, you can't just put random values just to get pass this error. You're going to mess up the integrity of the data.

Comment: I mean it just for an example

Answer (score -2):

group_id is not null field ... so if you want to store NULL value then make it nullable other wise you can store 0 or '' blank value.
.

```
INSERT INTO `bitauth_users` (`username`, `password`, `active`, `activation_code`, `group_id`, `password_last_set`) VALUES ('FAAN', '0884e4e5928d672b182a37b885b5e6ec', 1, '7c6ef5bd05fd2d189df64da76e76017ecec7d233', '', '2016-06-23 04:07:08')
```

Comment: pls do i need to set this value using phpmyadmin or do i go to the file directory as specified and look for line 330 to make the changes

Comment: Assuming group_id is a foreign key, you can't just put random values just to get pass this error. You're going to mess up the integrity of the data.

Answer (score -2):

In your sql,tha VALUES part,the group_id is setted to NULL.The error msg is "Column 'group_id' cannot be null".So you can convert NULL to zero.
The sql can be like this:

```
INSERT INTO `bitauth_users` 
 (`username`,`password`, `active`, `activation_code`, `group_id`,`password_last_set`) 
VALUES 
('FAAN', '0884e4e5928d672b182a37b885b5e6ec', 1, '7c6ef5bd05fd2d189df64da76e76017ecec7d233',
 0, '2016-06-23 04:07:08')
```

Hope this can help you!

Comment: Assuming group_id is a foreign key, you can't just put random values just to get pass this error. You're going to mess up the integrity of the data.

Comment: i am checking phpmyadmin and on the Table: bitauth_users structure ,under the group id, the Null colum is already 0, yet still i am still having the error message even when the group id is not set to NULL but just 0

Comment: so what do i do and where do i get the group id value to use

Comment: @GFunk you need to take a step back and learn how tables in databases work. How they relate to each other and what primary/foreign keys are.